# DllMain is not called, even with extern C

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, dll, code-injection

I am trying to inject a DLL into a x64 process. My injector is written in C#, compiled in 64 bits.
The DllMain function is not called, even if everything is ok when using the injector. Here is my DllMain.cpp code :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "InternalLoop.h"

static HANDLE MainThread;
static const WORD MAX_CONSOLE_LINES = 500;

#ifdef _DEBUG

void InstanciateConsole()
{
    int hConHandle;
    UINT64 lStdHandle;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO coninfo;
    FILE *fp;

    AllocConsole();

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &coninfo);
    coninfo.dwSize.Y = MAX_CONSOLE_LINES;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coninfo.dwSize);

    lStdHandle = reinterpret_cast< UINT64 >(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    lStdHandle = reinterpret_cast< UINT64 >(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE));
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "r");
    *stdin = *fp;
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    lStdHandle = reinterpret_cast< UINT64 >(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE));
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
    *stderr = *fp;
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    std::ios::sync_with_stdio();
}

#endif

void initLoop()
{
    InternalLoop MainLoop;
    MainLoop.MainLoop();
}

extern "C" BOOL APIENTRY 
DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
        DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
        LPVOID lpReserved
        )
    {
        Beep(750, 1000);
        switch (ul_reason_for_call)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: //When the injector is called.
            InstanciateConsole();

            printf("%s\n", "Creating thread ...");

            MainThread = CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)initLoop, 0, 0, NULL);

            if (MainThread) 
                printf("%s\n", "Thread created !");
            else 
                printf("%s\n", "Thread is not created :(");

            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            if (MainThread) 
                CloseHandle(MainThread);
            break;
        }
        return TRUE;
}
```

The beep is not executed, and I can't find why ...

`
public enum DllInjectionResult
    {
        DllNotFound,
        GameProcessNotFound,
        InjectionFailed,
        Success
    }

```
public sealed class DllInjector
{
    static readonly IntPtr INTPTR_ZERO = (IntPtr)0;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, int bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, IntPtr dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int WriteProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] buffer, uint size, int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpThreadAttribute, IntPtr dwStackSize, IntPtr lpStartAddress,
        IntPtr lpParameter, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpThreadId);

    static DllInjector _instance;

    public static DllInjector GetInstance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new DllInjector();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public DllInjector() { }

    public DllInjectionResult Inject(string sProcName, string sDllPath)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(sDllPath))
        {
            return DllInjectionResult.DllNotFound;
        }

        uint _procId = 0;

        Process[] _procs = Process.GetProcesses();
        for (int i = 0; i < _procs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (_procs[i].ProcessName == sProcName)
            {
                _procId = (uint)_procs[i].Id;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (_procId == 0)
        {
            return DllInjectionResult.GameProcessNotFound;
        }

        if (!bInject(_procId, sDllPath))
        {
            return DllInjectionResult.InjectionFailed;
        }

        return DllInjectionResult.Success;
    }

    bool bInject(uint pToBeInjected, string sDllPath)
    {
        IntPtr hndProc = OpenProcess((0x2 | 0x8 | 0x10 | 0x20 | 0x400), 1, pToBeInjected);

        if (hndProc == INTPTR_ZERO)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OpenProcess have failed.");
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr lpLLAddress = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

        if (lpLLAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetProcAddress have failed.");
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr lpAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, (IntPtr)sDllPath.Length, (0x1000 | 0x2000), 0X40);

        if (lpAddress == INTPTR_ZERO)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("VirtualAllocEx have failed.");
            return false;
        }

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sDllPath);

        if (WriteProcessMemory(hndProc, lpAddress, bytes, (uint)bytes.Length, 0) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WriteProcessMemory have failed.");
            return false;
        }

        if (CreateRemoteThread(hndProc, (IntPtr)null, INTPTR_ZERO, lpLLAddress, lpAddress, 0, (IntPtr)null) == INTPTR_ZERO)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CreateRemoteThread have failed.");
            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            return false;
        }

        CloseHandle(hndProc);

        return true;
    }
}
```

`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DllInjector injector = new DllInjector();
            string process = "chrome";
            string dll = "hv100.dll";

            Console.Write("Waiting for chrome.exe to be executed ...\n");

            while (!IsProcessOpen(process)) Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine("Chrome found !");
            DllInjectionResult result = injector.Inject(process, dll);
            switch (result) {
                case DllInjectionResult.Success:
                    Console.WriteLine("Injection is sucessful !");
                    break;
                case DllInjectionResult.DllNotFound:
                    Console.WriteLine("Dll not found.");
                    break;
                case DllInjectionResult.GameProcessNotFound:
                    Console.WriteLine("Game not found.");
                    break;
                case DllInjectionResult.InjectionFailed:
                    Console.WriteLine("Injection failed. Something has gone wrong.");
                    break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return;
        }
    }
```

`
EDIT : added injector code

Comment: The `DllMain` function is not designed to execute certain API functions.  See here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#general_best_practices

Comment: Ok, but even the Beep isn't performed. And what function can I use instead of createThread ?

Comment: Bottom line is that `DllMain` is best used for simple initializations, i.e allocating memory, setting globals to a certain value, initialize synchronization objects, etc.  Also, as the answer stated, use `OutputDebugString` to display messages.  Do *not* use `printf` or even `MessageBox` to output messages.

Comment: Is the Dll already asynchronous from the main process upon injection ?

Comment: We cannot see the injector, and we don't know, if it really does, what you think. Maybe the DLL never gets injected into the target process. Impossible to answer, without seeing all relevant code.

Comment: @IInspectable Added injector code

Comment: Are you running the injector as admin?

Comment: No, should it change something ?

EDIT : Runned as admin changed nothing.

Comment: The injector is pretty much all wrong. For one, it retrieves the address of `LoadLibraryA` in the **calling** process, not in the target process. It then attempts to create a remote thread, calling `LoadLibraryA`, but doesn't care about calling conventions at all. The x64 ABI demands, that the first 4 arguments are passed in registers, and the *lpParameter* argument doesn't do, what you think it does. For the time being, you'll have better chances succeeding, if you tried to learn to play, instead of hacking the game.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't ask for any judgements, thanks for your technical explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, rewrote the injector in C++, and the WriteProcessMemory need the absolute path of the dll, or I have to put the dll + injector in the home director of the target executable.